# Get text element from a javascript alert using webdriver

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium webdrive in c# for learning and writing automated tests and i have come across this situation:

Say you have a website like this: http://referencewebapp.qaautomation.net/register.php and you get the pop-up with the error message as a javascript alert(if you press Register without filling in any info, for example). What i need to do is to check what error message (the text) is in the alert.

I cannot use driver.FindElement or drive.PageSource as i cannot see the source code for it. I read about trying to select/change the frame([Selenium cannot get alert thrown in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320413/selenium-cannot-get-alert-thrown-in-iframe)), but i don't know how the frameID. Is there any way i can find and check that text?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Text;
```

should be all you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get the text of an alert (dialog) by using selenium Alert object.

for example:

```
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    String alertText = alert.getText();
    if (alertText.equals("error...")) {

        // Do Something...

        // dismiss alert
        alert.dismiss();

    }
```

More information in the [selenium 2.0 documentation.](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.alert.html)